# Function to replace text in arrays C++

Tags: c++, string, function, variable-assignment

I am having a problem. I need to make a function called replaceText that replaces a targeted text with new text. The null character is not included and if no targetText is found then there is no text replacement.

The parameters are two arrays targetText[] and replacementText[]. This is for an assignment and I cannot use str. Here is my code so far.

```
void SimpleString::replaceText(char targetText[], char replacementText[])
    {
        for ( int i = 0; i < MAX_LIST; i++)
        {
            if( replacementText[i] > MAX_LIST)
            {
                throw SimpleStringOverflowException("SimpleStringOverflowException: Resulting SImpleString too large.");
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Use `std::string` instead of char arrays. It is a lot better.

Comment: Maybe I'm the only one who doesn't get it but as I see it this is his homework and I doubt that he's allowed to use std::string or boost.

Comment: Is there some reason you can't just use string::replace or should you have used the Homework tag because you need to write it for yourself?

Comment: *"This is for an assignment and I can't use str"*. People, read.

Comment: @Duck, The [tag:homework] tag is deprecated.

Comment: @chris - so it is.  Then as far as I am concerned this isn't really C++.  Might as well just put in the C tag.

Comment: @Duck There's scope resolution operator and `throw`, what else do you want to make it C++? :)

Comment: @Duck, Actually quite true. Without `std::string`, any solution is going to be more C-ish. @^, Those aren't relavent.

Comment: @Kayla If there's no null character at the end of arrays and if you don't know the length, then I don't see how you can solve this.

Comment: @chris - the more I think about it I can go either way on this too.  Maybe I am just grouchy being stuck inside on a beautiful autumn afternoon.  Kayla, if this is your own string class and you aren't keeping a length variable and no null byte is included you can't do this.

Comment: What is `SimpleString`? What do you want to do when the target and replacement strings are different lengths? Add padding? Truncate? Reallocate memory?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here you go:

```
    void replace_text(char targetText[], char replacementText[])

{


    int i;
        if(strlen(replacementText) > 0 )
    {

        for(i=0;i<strlen(replacementText);i++)
        {           
            targetText[i] = replacementText[i];
        }
        for(i = strlen(replacementText) ; i < strlen (targetText) ; i++)
            targetText[i] = '\0';
    }

}
```

I assume you can use strlen....right? if not let me know...

Comment: use int sizeOfArray = sizeof(myArray) / sizeof(myArray[0]) to determine length of char array

Comment: Yes we can use strlen. Thank you for your help. That got me on the right track.

Answer (score 0):

it is so simple dear, just assign characters one by one.
i.e. targetText[i]=replacementText[i] 
now just iterate the i until it ends the replacementtext or targettext.